# How to combine an radio input with a text input

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to build a combined radio / text input for an "other" field in a form.

```
<input id="artist" type="radio" name="artist" value="Other">
<input id="other-artist" type="text" name="other_artist" placeholder="Other Artist"/>
```

I can't figure out how to click inside the text input and have the radio selected. I tried wrapping the text input in a label but that did not work.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. You want the `radio` to be checked by clicking on text box. Then how do you unchecked the `radio` again when required some time later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a onclick event to de input and check the radio like this.

```
<input id="artist" type="radio" name="artist" value="Other">

<input id="other-artist" type="text" name="other_artist"placeholder="Other Artist" 
onClick="selectRadio()" />
```

and the js

```
selectRadio = () => {
     var radio = document.getElementById("artist");
     radio.checked = true;
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/a370mykk/)

hope this help.